# Issue Passing an Optional Argument through Theorem Name with thmtools

Tags: theorems, optional-arguments, thmtools

I am using `thmtools` to create theorems, and I sometimes want the theorem name to include math symbols. In this particular project, I have used `xargs` to create a command that uses an optional argument, however, an error compiles whenever I attempt to pass the optional argument through for the theorem name.

I have included a MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xargs}

\declaretheorem{thm}

\newcommandx{\R}[1][1]{\mathbb{R}^{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[$\R$]
    This theorem works.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}[$\R[n]$]
    This theorem does not work.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas about what is causing this problem and how I can pass the argument through the theorem name?

In the log file, I get the following report:

```
! Argument of \\R has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.21 \begin{thm}[$\R[n]
                       $]
?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider protecting the argument passed to `thm` by wrapping it inside `{`...`}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xargs}

\declaretheorem{thm}

\newcommandx{\R}[1][1]{R^{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}[$\R$]
    This theorem works.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}[{$\R[n]$}]
    This theorem does not work.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```